# Regular Expression Tester: unexpected result

Tags: regex

Why does this [expression tester](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html) with the regex `\d+(?:-\d+)*` on the String `"123-234-24-f"` return "sucessful match"?

Comment: @Chris311 What other result would you expect and why?

Comment: @Chris311 Carry on with regex tutorials. They are very useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regular expression will match the initial "123-234-24" of your string. The `*` indicates 0 or more matches, which, in this case, matches twice.

To make sure that the *whole* string matches the regular expression, add the "^" and "$" anchors. Thus `^\d+(?:-\d+)*$` will not match your string.

The `^` indicates that the match must start at the beginning of the string and the `$` indicates that the match must end at the end of the string (or at the beginning and end of a line in multiline mode, though I have not managed to enter new lines in the tester that you linked to).

Comment: `^$` will test start and end of string by default. It will match start and end of line when `m` flag is specified.

Comment: You're absolutely right. I'm too used to `sed`. I will amend my answer. Thanks.

Comment: Ah ok, now i got it. The regex matches '123' and that's it. Thanks.